# Decide Vimfiles directory from Bash

Tags: bash, vim, cross-platform, dotfiles

I would like to get the `vimfiles` directory of the user. Given that users can presumable use directories other than `~/.vim/`, retrieving the directory from `vim`'s `vimfiles` variable would be the optimal cross-platform way to do it. But how?

I think calling something like `vim -q -c COMMAND` might actually be the solution, but am not sure about the `COMMAND` to be used.

Comment: In case you already read my answer, please re-read it. The original version actually gave a bad result, because `--cmd` runs *before* the vimrc is loaded. So it would only tell you the default path, not the user's actual path. The new version should be accurate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this will do what you want.

```
vim -c ':exec ":silent !echo ".&rtp | exec ":q!"'
```

On my laptop this is the result (reformatted for readability).

```
/Users/dan/.vim,/Users/dan/.vim/bundle/ack,/Users/dan/.vim/bundle/fugitive,
/Users/dan/.vim/bundle/json,/Users/dan/.vim/bundle/my-ackmore,
/Users/dan/.vim/bundle/my-endwise,/Users/dan/.vim/bundle/pathogen,
/Users/dan/.vim/bundle/perl,/Users/dan/.vim/bundle/pgsql,
/Users/dan/.vim/bundle/quickrun,/Users/dan/.vim/bundle/repeat,
/Users/dan/.vim/bundle/signify,/Users/dan/.vim/bundle/statline,
/Users/dan/.vim/bundle/surround,/Users/dan/.vim/bundle/tcomment,
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles,/usr/share/vim/vim73,
/usr/share/vim/vimfiles/after,/Users/dan/.vim/after
```

You can read more about Vim startup in `:help $VIM`.

**UPDATE:** as requested, here is a variation to only show the first entry in the list, which I think should be *vimfiles*:

```
vim -c ':exec ":silent !echo " . split(&rtp,",")[0] | exec ":q!"'
```

Comment: Using `echo &rtp` will avoid the `runtimepath=` bit of the output.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - my previous answer gave an incorrect result so I have fixed that, and I used `&rtp` this time.

Comment: Why the complication of using `:exec` and strings? Why not just `vim --cmd ''echo &rtp|q'` like you had originally? Ah. The extra spaces and terminal warning.

Comment: Oh, for after use `-c`.

Comment: Yeah, it wanted to load an interactive edit window unless it was like this. As to why switching from `--cmd`, that gave the wrong result because it runs before vimrc is loaded. So it only tells you default path, not the user's actual path.

Comment: If you don't want to actually execute the users' .vimrc (which might potentially have unwanted side effects) you could use `vim -u NONE -c ...` .

Comment: @DaanBakker That is true about using `-u NONE` but it should be noted that doing that will just tell you the default paths, not what the user is using.

Comment: @DanLowe I tried running your solution, but quickly realized that it is giving the `runtimepath` rather than the user `vimfiles` directory which is `~/.vim/` in most OS. Anyway to get that? More parsing based on your result? Maybe we could get that directly from Vim, right?

Comment: @hyiltiz I updated my answer with a variant that shows only item 0 from the list, I believe that should (*should*) always be vimfiles.

Comment: @DanLowe Thank you so much Dan! I know almost nothing about vimscript, and did not even know [] indexing (did not even know that was a list). I knew there should be a way to get that out from vim without further parsing through Awk. Thank you so mcuh!